# Turning a language object into a String in R

Tags: r, string

I am writing some code in R to handle errors/warnings.

The condition object i get back is a list of a message as string and a call object, representing the function call, that caused the error. I want to have a string that is the same as if i simply used print() on the call object. However using as.character() or paste() gives back a vector of multiple strings representing the function name and parameters.

Is there an easy way to do this or do i have to build the string myself?

Comment: An example of what you want and what you've tried should help us help you.

Comment: Perhaps `deparse`? But I agree, without a specific example it's difficult to tell.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `deparse`:

```
x <- call("sum",1:10)
as.character(x)
[1] "sum"  "1:10"
deparse(x)
[1] "sum(1:10)"
```

Comment: Thank you this works. I also found capture.output() myself, which seems to do the same thing.